# Visual basic Dot Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

I don't hit any error with below code but the file is not uploaded into google drive. Anything that i've missed? Please help.

NOTE: cred.json is the file generated from google developer console.

```
Dim Service As New DriveService

Dim cred As Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential

Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload

Dim body As New Data.File()

cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("D:\cred.json")
      
cred.CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive)

Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = cred})

body.Name = IO.Path.GetFileName("D:\Test.txt")

body.MimeType = "text/plain"

 Using Stream = New FileStream("D:\Test.txt", FileMode.Open)

         UploadRequest = Service.Files.Create(body, Stream, body.MimeType)

         UploadRequest.SupportsAllDrives = True

         UploadRequest.Upload()
End Using
```

Comment: Is upload async?

Comment: i think you should see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646527/upload-and-download-to-google-drive-using-vb-net-form

Comment: @nbk that answer has nothing to do with the issue above and its in C# not VB.

Comment: @DaImTo it is easily to convert the c# to vb net and it completly answers the question

Comment: @nbk it may be easy for you to swap languages but the question is for VB not C# the author may not know C#.  Also the accepted answer shows a file.list, using Oauth2 with C#. I fail to see how this will help with a upload issue for service accounts using VB .net.   By showing someone a file.list example for winforms from 2013 using Oauth2 with C#.

Comment: If you want to show them a C# example try this [Google API to upload files using the Authentication Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29009874/1841839)

Comment: @DaImTo it has to be asynchronous , that is the basic problem in his code, as the authentification works,. or he would get another error

Comment: The basic issue is not with their code there is no error because the code worked. They are looking in the wrong place.  They are not setting parents, so its going to the root folder of the service accounts drive account.

Comment: @nbk the accepted answer you mentioned above using Oauth, i manage to upload & download to google drive using Oauth but when using service account nothing uploaded.

Comment: @DaImTo I agree that it's preferable to give examples in VB where possible, but it's an important skill for a VB developer to be able to translate C# into VB.  There are a lot of things where there is sample C# code but not VB.

Comment: Hi @Craig i respect your opinion, but when a question is asked in a specific language it is best to give answers in that language.     Giving someone an answer in an unfamiliar language will not always be helpful and may cause more confusion especially to new developers just learning.  [how to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  You  may also want to consider that the code for OAUTH2 is nothing like the code for a service account.   Oauth2 code would be of no help at all in this question even in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been a while since I have used vb .net sorry it took so long.  This example should show you how to properly load the service account key file and upload your file to a directory of your choice.

Just remember to share the folder with the service account email address.  If you open the json key file its the only variable that has an @ in it.

```
Imports System
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Upload

Module Program
     Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        
        REM path to your service account key file. 
        Const  pathToServiceAccountKeyFile = "C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\ServiceAccountCred.json"

        REM load the service account credentials and use drive scope 
        Dim credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(pathToServiceAccountKeyFile).CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive)
         
        Rem Create the drive service 
        Dim service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() with { 
                                          .HttpClientInitializer = credential
                                          })
         Task.Run(Async Function()
             Await UploadFileAsync(service)
         End Function).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        
    End Sub
     
     Private Async Function UploadFileAsync(service As DriveService) As Task(Of Boolean)
        
         Const FilePath As String = "C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Data\dummy.txt"
         
         Dim plist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

         REM Folder id to upload the file To
         Const idFolderSave = "0B5pJkOVaKccEYm5pVTJCWGFJbGM"
        
         plist.Add(idFolderSave) 'Set parent folder

         If (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
             Dim fileMetadata = New File() With {
                     .Name = "Test",
                     .MimeType = "text/plain",
                     .Parents = plist
                     }

             Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload

             Using stream = New System.IO.FileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
                 request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "text/plain")
                 request.Fields = "id, parents"
                 dim results = await request.UploadAsync()
                 
                 If (results.Status = UploadStatus.Failed)
                     Console.WriteLine("failed")
                     Console.WriteLine(results.Exception)
                     
                 else
                    Dim file As File = request.ResponseBody
                    Console.WriteLine("File upload: " + file.Id)
                 End If
                     
             End Using

            
         Else
             Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + FilePath)
         End If
     End Function
   
End Module
```

I will make sure to document this some where i dont think we currently have any visual basic samples any where for the library.

Comment: @DalmTo Yes, i did share a folder with the service account. I actually did tried before body.Parents.add(folder id), but nothing happened. Anything wrong?

Comment: try a files.list are you sure there is no fule? I cant see you using parents in your code.    I will run your code in the morning other than missing parents it looks right to me.

Comment: @DalmTo I've just tried files.list, Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = Service.Files.List() request.Q = "'Folder ID' in parents" request.Execute() with using the same  credential as above, i hit error, "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid Credentials[401]Errors [Message[Invalid Credentials] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[authError] Domain[global]]", any idea?

Comment: Okay you have me curios.   Give me a minute to install VB.net

Comment: I recommend using the new FromFile method for loading the credentials.   Makes it easer.

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for pointing out the issue within my code. I slighly change my code base on your example and suggestion, its now working! You are a life saver.

Comment: np I will be releasing this sample soon with a YouTube video.   should help others in your situation 