# Having problems using Google sheet as a source in SSIS

Tags: ssis, google-api, google-oauth

I was able to import data from a Google sheet into SQL Server at one point using the method detailed in this [article](http://sqldeveloperramblings.blogspot.com/2010/06/ssis-google-spreadsheets-data-source.html).  Google deprecated ClientLogin which broke this method and I have been trying to get this functionality back up and running.

I turned to using OAuth which a service account to try and authenticate to Google as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324093/how-use-google-oauth2-using-serviceaccount-in-net) but cannot get it to work within an Integration Services Project.

In the project I create a data flow task with a script component as a source. I use the following code in the script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
    {
        ListFeed objListFeed;

        public override void PreExecute()
        {
            base.PreExecute();

            string keyFilePath = @"C:\key.p12";    // found in developer console
            string serviceAccountEmail = "myaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com";   // found in developer console
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) //create credential using certigicate
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/" } //this scopr is for spreadsheets, check google scope FAQ for others
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Wait(); //request token

            var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("My App User Agent");
            requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", credential.Token.AccessToken));

            SpreadsheetsService myService = new SpreadsheetsService("my-service"); //create your old service
            myService.RequestFactory = requestFactory; //add new request factory to your old service

            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery(); //do the job as you done it before
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = myService.Query(query);

            WorksheetQuery objWorkSheetQuery = new WorksheetQuery("sheet-id", "private", "full");
            WorksheetFeed objWorkSheetFeed = myService.Query(objWorkSheetQuery);
            WorksheetEntry objWorkSheet = (WorksheetEntry)objWorkSheetFeed.Entries[0];

            AtomLink objListFeedLink = objWorkSheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);

            ListQuery objListQuery = new ListQuery(objListFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
            objListFeed = myService.Query(objListQuery);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.
        ///
        /// You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
        /// </summary>
        public override void PostExecute()
        {
            base.PostExecute();
            /*
             * Add your code here
             */
        }

        public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
        {
            foreach (ListEntry objRow in objListFeed.Entries)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.responseid = objRow.Elements[0].Value;
                Output0Buffer.deptid = Convert.ToInt16(objRow.Elements[1].Value);
                Output0Buffer.timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(objRow.Elements[3].Value);
                Output0Buffer.username = objRow.Elements[4].Value;
                Output0Buffer.department = objRow.Elements[2].Value;
                Output0Buffer.extractdate = DateTime.Now;
            }

            Output0Buffer.EndOfRowset();
        }

    }
```

I build the script and get no errors but when I try and run the package I get the following runtime error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices,
>   Version=1.9.3.19383, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I added a reference to Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices in my script project so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I've created a console application project with similar code where I use NuGet to reference the Google Apis Auth Client Library and the code runs fine.  I have tried doing the same thing in my script project but get the following error when trying to build the script:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding all dll's in the NuGet package into the GAC and then referencing from there. I then faced a version dependency error which I overcame by adding a binding redirect in my machine.config. Not the most elegant solution but I just needed to make it work and other methods I tried weren't meeting with success.