# How to authenticate in Google Spreadsheet Api V4 with Server Key

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use google spreadsheets with server key (created in console.cloud.google.com) like this

```
var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "myappname",
        ApiKey = "mykey"
    });
```

But after first request i'm receiving an error

```
Message[The request does not have valid authentication credentials.]
```

So how to authenticate using only server key?

May be it's better to use service account credentials to work with api from server (if it's possible of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [code written by Владимир Рак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324093/how-use-google-oauth2-using-serviceaccount-in-net):

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("pathTo***.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var serviceAccountEmail = "********-*********@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var userAccountEmail = "******@gmail.com";
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                   {
                       Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                       User = userAccountEmail
```

`}.FromCertificate(certificate));

    // Create the service.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "*****",
    });`

Comment: Yep, this is for service account, and probably it works (at least in my case it works with another cloud apis :) ). But question was about server key

Comment: You cannot access Google sheets with a server API key. Google sheets is considered to be private information. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158857?hl=en

Comment: You can use a server API key, but the requested sheet must be public. https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing